# How to Insert new record with a table have two foreign keys in Spring Boot and Mysql

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

I need to insert a new record to request a table. Here is the ER Diagram.
[ER Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFV0p.jpg)

I need to know how to include the relevant user-id and the category id. these two ids are in two different tables. user id means the authenticated user's id and the category is selected by the user from the client-side.

This is the request model.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sample_requests")
public class SampleRequest extends UserDateAudit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Category category;


    private String description;

    private Boolean approved;

    @NotNull
    private Long quantity;

    public SampleRequest() {
    }
```

and this is the User model

```
public class User extends DateAudit {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "username")
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "email")
    @NaturalId
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Email
    private String email; 

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "password")
    @Size(max = 100)
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)   
    @JoinTable(name = "user_roles",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    )
    @Column(name = "roles")
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @Column(name = "designation")
    private String designation;

    @Column(name = "address")
    private String address;

    @Column(name = "organization")
    private String organization;

    @Column(name = "contactNo")
    private String contactNo;
```

And this is the Category Model.

```
public class Category extends UserDateAudit {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String testing_parameter_name;

    @NotNull
    private String reference_standard;

    @NotNull
    private String main_category_name;

    @NotNull
    private BigDecimal rate;

    private float discount;
```

I suppose to get the user id and the category id from the URL as path Variables. nd the rest from the request body as an object. So I implemented this method in Controller.

```
@PostMapping("/request/{categoryId}/{userId}")
    public SampleRequest createRequest(@PathVariable(value = "categoryId") Long categoryId, @PathVariable(value = "userId")
    Long userId, @Valid @RequestBody SampleRequest sampleRequest) throws ResourceNotFoundException{
            return categoryRepository.findById(categoryId).map(category -> {
                sampleRequest.setCategory(category);
                return sampleRequestRepository.save(sampleRequest);
            }).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Category Not Found","Category Id","Not Found" ));
    }
```

But it is wrong. Please explain a better way to solve this problem. is it ok to get the user id and category id as a path variable? And I am using Angular for front-end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send the user id and category id in the request body, because SampleRequest has them and you can develop it at below.

```
  @PostMapping("/request")
    public SampleRequest createRequest( @Valid @RequestBody SampleRequest sampleRequest) throws ResourceNotFoundException{

        SampleRequest sampleRequestCreated = sampleRequest;

        User user = userRepository.findById(sampleRequestCreated.getUser().getId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User Not Found","User Id","Not Found" ));

        Category category = categoryRepository.findById(sampleRequestCreated.getCategory().getId())
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Category Not Found","Category Id","Not Found" ));

        sampleRequestCreated.setUser(user);
        sampleRequestCreated.setCategory(category);

        return sampleRequestRepository.save(sampleRequestCreated);

    }
```

Comment: But after I got "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The given id must not be null!" error.

Answer (score 0):

If you go this way you have to return category and user by id and then create your object. Firstly make constructor with essential parameters and next make something like this:

```
User user = userRepo.findById(userId).orElseThrow();
Category category = categoryRepo.findById(categoryId).orElseThrow();

SampleRequest sampleRequest = new SampleRequest(user, category) // id will be generated automatically

sampleRequestRepo.save(sampleRequest);
```